# Pandas merge/faltten dataframe based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas

i have following data sample i am trying to flatten it out using pandas, i wanna flatten this data over Candidate_Name.

[image]

This is my implementation,

```
df= df.merge(df,on=('Candidate_Name'))
```

but i am not getting desired result. My desired output is as follows. So basically have all the rows that match **Candidate_Name** in a single row, where duplicate column names may suffix with **_x**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then flatten `MultiIndex` with same values for first groups and added numbers for another levels for avoid duplicated columns names:

```
df = df.set_index(['Candidate_Name', df.groupby('Candidate_Name').cumcount()]).unstack()
df.columns = [a if b == 0 else f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
```

Comment: the 2nd line has some syntax issue , can you please check?

Comment: Let me test it out please, i will get back to you

Comment: So a question, this approach will change column name too? or i have to explicitly pass column names to original dataframe?

Comment: @noobie-php - It change all columns names for duplicated rows.